# PHP file uploads doesnot read $_FILES['image']

Tags: php, file-upload

i have this input type

```
  <input class="btn btn-success" type="file" name="profile_image" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></input>
```

user will add the image file from here, and the PHP code to upload the file

```
if(isset($_FILES['profile_image']))
            {
                $image_type = $this->getImageType($_FILES['profile_image']);

                if($image_type == 'image')
                {
                    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['profile_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $filename = '123_'.uniqid().'.'.$extension;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_image']['tmp_name'], '../functions/images/images/'.$filename);
                }
            }
else
            {
                $filename = 'default_profile_image.jpg';
            }
```

and the `getImageType`

```
public function getImageType($file)
    {
        $imageMime = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
        $type = explode('/', $imageMime['mime']);
        return $type[0];
    }
```

but it does not read `$_FILES['profile_image']` and rather moves to else part. why does it not read $_FILES ? is there anything missing?

Comment: Maybe your `<form>` tag is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute? [Read more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this code in form tag
 `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```